# Hibernate - handle add (insert) when fk self-reference in another class

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have Hibernate configs as follows.

**CPUModel**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="org.example.CPUModel" table="cpu_model">
    <id name="cpuModelId" type="java.lang.Integer" unsaved-value="null">
      <column name="cpu_model_id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
      <column length="32" name="name"/>
    </property>
    <set name="softwares" inverse="true" lazy="false" table="cpu_model_software" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="cpu_sw_id desc">
      <key>
        <column name="cpu_model_id" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="org.example.CPUModelSoftware"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**CPUModelSoftware**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="org.example.CPUModelSoftware" table="cpu_model_software">
    <composite-id name="cpuModelSoftwarePK" class="org.example.CPUModelSoftwarePK">
      <key-property name="cpuModelId" column="cpu_model_id" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
      <key-property name="cpuSwId" column="cpu_sw_id" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one class="org.example.CPUSoftware" insert="false" update="false" fetch="select" name="cpuSw">
      <column name="cpu_sw_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Selecting values and updating works fine with this config, but inserting a completely new value just doesn't.

I get this error:

```
DEBUG Could not execute JDBC batch update [insert into exampledb.cpu_model_software (cpu_model_id, cpu_sw_id) values (?, ?)]
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'cpu_model_id' cannot be null
```

So Hibernate is trying to make an insert without first getting generated cpu_model_id from the DB, and setting then it for CPUModelSoftwarePK (see CPUModel Hibernate config)

So how do I tell Hibernate that it should first make an insert to cpu_model table. Then get the id from there and set the id for CPUModelSoftwarePK and make insert?

The db for CPUModelSoftware/PK is as follows.

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cpu_model_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cpu_sw_id      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and for CPUModel

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cpu_model_id   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**EDIT**

It seems that I wasn't nulling CPUModelSoftwarePK when making a new CPUModelSoftware. However now I am getting this:

```
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): org.example.CPUModelSoftware
```

Comment: try `<generator class="native"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, Hibernate doesn't support derived identities in mappings defined in `hbm.xml`. It means that Hibernate can't set value of `cpuModelId` automatically based on relationship between `CPUModel` and `CPUModelSoftware`.

Thus, you need to save `CPUModel` (with empty `softwares`) first, then you need to assign its generated identifier to the field of `CPUModelSoftware`'s compisite id, and save `CPUModelSoftware`.

Comment: Yup, this was the case. I had to first save the CPUModel object without having any references to CPUModelSoftware. After that just save again with CPUModelSoftware references. Somehow I thought that Hibernate would do this automagically, but world's not perfect. :-) Thanks!